# запрос формы не отравляется на почту

Tags: javascript, php, html, phpmailer

Сделал форму для отправки информации на почту, использую для этого phpMailer. оформил php и js.

В коде элемента запрос отрабатывает с кодом 200, но по факту письмо не приходит.
Подскажите, в чем причина?

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['number'];

require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail - > CharSet = 'utf-8';

// $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail - > isSMTP(); // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail - > Host = 'smtp.mail.ru'; // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail - > SMTPAuth = true; // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail - > Username = 'пишу сюда свою почту'; // Наш логин
$mail - > Password = 'сюда пароль'; // Наш пароль от ящика
$mail - > SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail - > Port = 465; // TCP port to connect to

$mail - > setFrom('моя почта', 'window'); // От кого письмо 
$mail - > addAddress('gojat38580@gekme.com'); // Add a recipient
$mail - > isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML

$mail - > Subject = 'Данные';
$mail - > Body = '
Пользователь оставил данные < br >
  Имя: ' . $name . ' < br >
  Номер телефона: ' . $phone . '
';

if (!$mail - > send()) {
  return false;
} else {
  return true;
}
```

```js
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "mailer/smart.php",
    data: $(this).serialize()
  }).done(function() {
    $(this).find("input").val("");
    $('#consultation').fadeOut();
    $('.overlay, #thanks').fadeIn('slow');


    $("form").trigger("reset");
  });
  return false;
});
```

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .56);
}

.overlay .overlay_modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 380px;
  min-height: 400px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 38px 40px 40px 40px;
}

.overlay .modal_close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -40px;
  font-size: 41px;
  line-height: 21px;
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.overlay .modal_subtitle {
  color: #0d0d0d;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
}

.overlay .modal_descr {
  color: #0d0d0d;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
}

.overlay .modal_mini {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 380px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 38px 40px 40px 40px;
  min-height: 140px;
}

.overlay .overlay_form .form-control {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.overlay .overlay_form button {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.overlay .button_submit {
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#thanks {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>

<body>
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="overlay_modal" id="consultation">
      <div class="modal_close">&times;</div>
      <div class="modal_subtitle">Просто заполните форму заявки</div>
      <div class="modal_descr">и мы перезвоним вам в течении 10 минут</div>
      <form class="overlay_form">
        <input name="number" type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Ваш номер">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ваше имя">
        <br>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Заказать звонок</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="modal_mini" id="thanks">
    <div class="modal_close">&times;</div>
    <div class="modal_subtitle">Спасибо за вашу заявку!</div>
    <div class="modal_descr">Наш менеджер свяжется с вами в ближайшее время!</div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Как минимум поддержка встраивания PHP кода посредством `<script language="php"></script>` была удалена в PHP 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в политиках безопасности Google и Mail.ru, для оправки писем необходимо открыть доступ для работы сторонних приложений (в google это делается через *"Настройки"* - *"все настройки"* - *"Пересылка и POP/IMAP"* - *"Состояние IMAP - **включить**"*).

После этого в настройках двухфакторной аутентификации в самом низу есть "пароль приложений". Именно **ЕГО НУЖНО** вставлять в password.

Mail.ru сам отправил письмо, что для отправки через сторонние приложения нужен отдельный пароль, и прикрепил ссылку для его создания.

Для проверки работы вот [ссылка на тест SMTP запроса](https://www.gmass.co/smtp-test).